# GS020: Signatures data too short

Tags: gnosis-safe

I was trying to send Matic using a multisig 1/3 owners and I got this error on the Polygon chain.

I use Firefox + Metamask (v10.8.1) + Connected to Ledger as signer

Any idea why this error is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Probably because the txn hasn't had the required number of approving signatures

See https://github.com/gnosis/safe-contracts/blob/main/contracts/GnosisSafe.sol#L247